# Getting android Error

Tags: android

I am working on android google maps and I get an error when opening a particular activity I don't know what's causing the problem. I am running the application on my mobile device, when I remove the `googleApiClient` part by `setLocation`, then it works but not with the client, can you find out the error? Below is the code and exceptions.

```
package com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest;

import android.*;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class profile extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    ImageButton pr_img_btn;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private final static int MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION = 101;
    //AIzaSyAjxQKEZc9MHTH3f173Iv21Gw2c6IeUX2U

    //Main Activity Launching Method
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        pr_img_btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pr_img_btn);
        pr_img_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(profile.this, settings.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        //if the google play services are availble on the phone
        if (googleServicesAvailble()) {
            initMap();
        }

    }

    //Check For google play Services
    public boolean googleServicesAvailble() {
        GoogleApiAvailability gpa = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int avail = gpa.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (avail == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        } else if (gpa.isUserResolvableError(avail)) {
            Dialog dialog = gpa.getErrorDialog(this, avail, 0);
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(profile.this, "Can't connect to play store", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Initiate The map
    private void initMap() {
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFrag);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    //When the google map is initiated
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap Map) {
        googleMap = Map;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);
            }
        }

    }

    //Check for the runtime permissions, if they are granted or not
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { //If the permissions are granted
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                                .build();
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "This app requires location permissions to be granted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();//Make the location request
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);//For high accuracy
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(100);//Set interval to get the map updated in
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location == null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't get the Location ! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            LatLng ll = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
            CameraUpdate camUpd = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll);
            googleMap.animateCamera(camUpd);
        }
    }

    @Override public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}
    @Override public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}
    @Override public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {}
    @Override public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {}
    @Override public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {}
}
```

#### Error log:

```
07-12 00:19:29.017 17215-17215/? E/Zygote: v2
07-12 00:19:29.017 17215-17215/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10252
07-12 00:19:29.017 17215-17215/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
07-12 00:19:29.018 17215-17215/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
07-12 00:19:29.018 17215-17215/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0005, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
07-12 00:19:29.020 17215-17215/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest 
07-12 00:19:29.024 17215-17215/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
07-12 00:19:29.111 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest-1/lib/arm64
07-12 00:19:29.127 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest, real application class is null.
07-12 00:19:30.987 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest-1/lib/arm64
07-12 00:19:31.024 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
07-12 00:19:31.237 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-12 00:19:31.392 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
07-12 00:19:31.446 17215-17564/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-12 00:19:34.600 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
07-12 00:19:36.439 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/QPerformance.jar
07-12 00:19:36.445 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
07-12 00:19:37.069 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
07-12 00:19:37.084 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
07-12 00:19:38.228 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
07-12 00:19:38.255 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
07-12 00:19:40.025 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest I/zzbx: Making Creator dynamically
07-12 00:19:40.074 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
07-12 00:19:40.118 17215-17220/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=26KB
07-12 00:19:40.118 17215-17220/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest I/art: After code cache collection, code=25KB, data=22KB
07-12 00:19:40.118 17215-17220/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
07-12 00:19:40.177 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 11011000
07-12 00:19:40.182 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 11055440
07-12 00:19:40.493 17215-17987/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest W/agl: copyMemory is missing from platform - proto runtime falling back to safer methods.
07-12 00:19:40.513 17215-17977/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
07-12 00:19:40.513 17215-17977/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
07-12 00:19:40.574 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest I/Choreographer: Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-12 00:19:40.770 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
07-12 00:19:40.963 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
07-12 00:19:41.037 17215-17215/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest, PID: 17215
                                                                                 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest.profile cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
                                                                                     at com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest.profile.onConnected(profile.java:132)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zzn(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbco.zzm(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcc.zzpY(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcc.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcw.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbbh.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzn.zzrj(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze.zzs(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi.zzrk(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
07-12 00:19:42.573 17215-18002/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
07-12 00:19:42.608 17215-18002/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:3
07-12 00:19:42.609 17215-18002/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 3
07-12 00:19:42.655 17215-18002/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000004/n/arm64-v8a
```

Comment: (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) remove this, line 132

Comment: Logcat tells you the error: " com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest.profile cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener"

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
 LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
```

The last parameter needs to be a Looper object or null. You are trying to cast your class with `this` to a Listener object. None of them should be the third parameter, instead try it with `null`

```
 LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, null);
```

Third Parameter described in API:

> The Looper
>
> object whose message queue will be used to implement the callback
>   mechanism, or null to make callbacks on the calling thread.

Answer (score 0):

[`android.location.LocationListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) and [`com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener) are *not* the same class. Change your imports from this:

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
```

To this:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.Location;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
```

Comment: What are the errors? Also, did you *add* them or *replace* them?